# Separating runon text in script

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have the following csv input:

```
XiaoLi,6705462234,lxiao@unc.edu,NC764
NatkinPook,8044344528,wnatkin@vcu.edu,VA22345
EliziMoe,5208534566,emoe@ncsu.edu,AZ85282
MaTa,4345667345,mta@yahoo.com,TX91030
DianaCheng,5203456789,dcheng@asu.edu,WY4587
JacksonFive,5206564573,jfive@ncsu.edu,AZ85483
AdiSrikanthReddy,6578904566,sadi1@asu.edu,WS67854
```

I would like it to output the following:

```
Xiao Li 6705462234 lxiao@unc.edu NC 764
Natkin Pook 8044344528 wnatkin@vcu.edu VA 22345
Elizi Moe 5208534566 emoe@ncsu.edu AZ 85282
Ma Ta 4345667345 mta@yahoo.com TX 91030
Diana Cheng 5203456789 dcheng@asu.edu WY 4587
Jackson Five 5206564573 jfive@ncsu.edu AZ 85483
Adi SrikanthReddy 6578904566 sadi1@asu.edu WS 67854
```

(`FirstName LastName PhoneNumber UserID@Email State Zip`)

This is what I have so far

```
 awk -F "," ' {print $1, $4, $3, $6}' data3
```

I am having trouble separating Firstname and Lastname from each other, and State and zipcode are also running together. How would I be able to separate these two cases?

I'm wanting to use awk, is there a way I can use something like [A-Z] to separate them at their uppercase letter?

Comment: Some of the "zip codes" in your last column don't appear to be zip codes.  Also how should it handle a name like "AdiSrikanthReddy" where there are three capital letters?  Also I hope those aren't real phone numbers and email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that user steeldriver's answer has already been accepted, but I thought to offer what I think is a shorter, simpler, and easier to read option. At the very least, it demonstrates some other features of awk (and the OP can always change his/her mind):

```
awk '
  { gsub(","," ")
    $0=gensub("([[:upper:]])([[:digit:]])","\\1 \\2","g")
    $0=gensub("([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])","\\1 \\2","g")
    print
  }' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

At least with `gawk` (GNU awk) and `mawk`, you could use the `match` function to find the index of a lowercase-uppercase or uppercase-digit transition, and then use `substr` to cut-and-shut the string:

```
awk -F, '
  {c = match($1,/[a-z][A-Z]/)} 
  c>0 {$1 = sprintf("%s %s", substr($1,1,c), substr($1,c+1))}
  {c = match($4,/[A-Z][0-9]/)} 
  c>0 {$4 = sprintf("%s %s", substr($4,1,c), substr($4,c+1))}
  1' file.csv
Xiao Li 6705462234 lxiao@unc.edu NC 764
Natkin Pook 8044344528 wnatkin@vcu.edu VA 22345
Elizi Moe 5208534566 emoe@ncsu.edu AZ 85282
Ma Ta 4345667345 mta@yahoo.com TX 91030
Diana Cheng 5203456789 dcheng@asu.edu WY 4587
Jackson Five 5206564573 jfive@ncsu.edu AZ 85483
Adi SrikanthReddy 6578904566 sadi1@asu.edu WS 67854
```

If your `$4` really is a US zipcode, then AFAIK the format is fixed and you could skip the second `match` and just do

```
awk -F, '                                                                                          
  {c = match($1,/[a-z][A-Z]/)} 
  c>0 {$1 = sprintf("%s %s", substr($1,1,c), substr($1,c+1))} 
  {$4 = sprintf("%s %s", substr($4,1,2), substr($4,3))}
  1' file.csv
```

It's a little tidier if you have a regex engine that allows zero-length assertions - such as Perl:

```
perl -F, -ne '
  print join " ", map { s/(?<=[[:lower:]])(?=[[:upper:]])|(?<=[[:upper:]])(?=[[:digit:]])/ /; $_ } @F
' file.csv
Xiao Li 6705462234 lxiao@unc.edu NC 764
Natkin Pook 8044344528 wnatkin@vcu.edu VA 22345
Elizi Moe 5208534566 emoe@ncsu.edu AZ 85282
Ma Ta 4345667345 mta@yahoo.com TX 91030
Diana Cheng 5203456789 dcheng@asu.edu WY 4587
Jackson Five 5206564573 jfive@ncsu.edu AZ 85483
Adi SrikanthReddy 6578904566 sadi1@asu.edu WS 67854
```